Replicating remote MacBook Pro setup on new Mac. Possibly with using TeamViewer. Alternatives to Migration Assistant?
I'm facing a challenge in setting up my new MacBook Pro with the configuration from my older MacBook Pro, which is located at a remote site. Here's my situation:

Remote MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018): Accessible via TeamViewer.

Local MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), that I want to set up (here with me).


Goal: Transfer the setup (data, apps, settings) - or close to a copy - from the remote Mac to the new one
Initially, I considered using Migration Assistant, but I've hit a roadblock:
Migration Assistant requires both Macs to be on the same network, which isn't possible with my remote setup.
There's no option within Migration Assistant to copy contents to iCloud or a similar cloud storage service.
While I have full control of the remote MacBook Pro via TeamViewer, I'm unsure how to proceed with transferring the complete setup. I'm seeking alternative methods to migrate everything from the remote Mac to my new local machine.
Some options I've considered:

Manual file transfer using TeamViewer
Using cloud services to sync data
Creating a disk image of the remote Mac's drive
Third-party remote backup solutions

Has anyone successfully completed a similar remote setup between two Macs? What methods or tools would you recommend for transferring everything (or as much as possible) from a remote Mac to a new local Mac?
I'm particularly interested in solutions that:

Can work over an internet connection (not requiring local network access)
Is compatible with TeamViewer remote access
Can transfer not just files, but also applications and system settings if possible
Is reasonably user-friendly

Any advice, step-by-step guides, or recommended tools would be greatly appreciated.

Get a TM machine backup of the original to a USB drive. Then get someone at the remote site to send you the disk by post or courier.

How much data are we talking about? (You mention TeamViewer supports file transfer, so you could first set up your new Mac, create an account, enable iCloud Desktop and Documents on both Macs (if there's enough space available), and then manually copy the ~/Library folder. You can disable iCloud later. Another option, If you have enough bandwidth, would be to copy your home folder on your old Mac to a temporary folder on your new Mac, and then overwrite your home folder on your new Mac with the contents of the temporary folder. After that, install all apps and configure system-wide settings.)

@mmmmmm Thank you for your suggestion. The Time Machine backup to a USB drive is an interesting option I hadn't considered. I might be able to get someone to attach a USB drive to the remote Mac. I'll look into that option!

@jaume Thank you for your detailed suggestion. Regarding the data volume, I will have to look into that next time I*m connected. I eestimate it's on the lower end, probably around 200GB of data to transfer, including documents, photos, application data. Have you tried this approach yourself?
Your iCloud and manual transfer method sounds promising,

I don't use the iCloud Desktop & Documents Folders feature myself but a family member does and it is rock solid. To transfer the documents you will need to subscribe to iCloud+, the lower tier (200 GB) should hopefully offer enough space. After files are synced you can stop the feature, check that you don't miss anything, and unsubscribe. There's some folder renaming that you will have to do, but it's straightforward. If you wish, I can post an answer detailing the steps to set it up. I'd like to add that a Time Machine backup, as mentioned by mmmmmm, if feasible, would be my preferred method.

@jaume Sounds like a good solution! I'd love to hear the steps to set it up! :)

Thank you for feedback, I've posted an answer with a detailed procedure to migrate data and app settings. Data migration should work, but I'm not 100% certain you will able to correctly migrate the app settings. Some settings, like printers and scanners, can't be migrated. I've written the answer to the best of my knowledge and hope is accurate, but haven't been able to test it. Read my post first to understand the procedure, and feel free to ask any questions.

Are you technically skilled enough to set up an ssh connection between the two Macs and transfer your Documents etc over?

That ssh connection which if you use tools like Forklift (which seems to be free with a nag that it is a trial) or Carbon CopyCloner or simply rsync is basically the same process as iCloud but needs no intermediate storage. This should be the same as using TeamViewer. However this and cloud services can get difficult in copying preferences etc.

I think it boils down to two options - Migration Assistant using the disk copy and external drives which do the whole and secondly manual using direct ssh or teamViewer connection or indirect via a cloud service - the latter will have issues with Preferences.

Time Machine is the preferred method to transfer data to another Mac. It is reliable and easy to use.
Since you can't use Time Machine in your setup, I'd recommend a procedure that relies on several iCloud features to transfer the bulk of your data and settings.
Note that you will need an Apple Account (formerly Apple ID) for this to work.
If you don't have an Apple Account yet, you can create one here (for more information, see How to create a new Apple Account).
The migration process is lengthy, but straightforward.
The first step is to set up your new Mac and synchronize all files in the Desktop and Documents folders:

Set up your new Mac and install all apps.

On your new Mac, sign in to your Apple Account.
Make sure that "Desktop & Documents Folders" in System Settings > Apple Account > iCloud > Drive (in macOS Sonoma or earlier, open System Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > iCloud Drive instead) is disabled:


Purchase an iCloud+ subscription for your Apple Account that exceeds your storage needs (see iCloud+ Plans and Pricing for details).

On your remote Mac:

Check System Settings to make sure that you are logged in with the same Apple Account you use on your new Mac.

Check that iCloud+ is displayed in System Settings > Apple Account > iCloud (in macOS Sonoma or earlier, open System Settings > Apple ID > iCloud):

As shown in the screenshot, you will probably see that some space is already in use.

Open System Settings > Apple Account > iCloud > Drive (in macOS Sonoma or earlier, open System Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > iCloud Drive instead) and turn on both "iCloud Drive" and "Desktop and Document Folders":

The synchronization will start immediately and may take several hours to complete.

Wait until all Desktop files and Documents are synchronized. You can check the progress with the "pie chart" status icon next to "iCloud Drive" in the sidebar of a Finder window:

The synchronization is complete when the "pie chart" status icon is no longer shown.



On your new Mac:

Remove all files on the Desktop and in the Documents folder.

Open a Finder window and select iCloud from the sidebar. You should see a folder with the same name as your remote Mac that contains a Desktop and a Documents folder. Copy the contents of those folders to the Desktop resp. the Documents folder on your new Mac.

Wait until all Desktop files and Documents have been copied to iCloud Drive and make some checks to verify that everything was copied.



On your remote Mac, turn off "Desktop & Documents Folders". To free up space to copy other data like movies, music and pictures, delete the Desktop and Documents folders in iCloud Drive.
When you turn off "Desktop & Documents Folders", a new Desktop and Documents folder is created on your Mac in your home folder, so you can safely delete the files in iCloud Drive.


The second step is to copy other files like movies, music and pictures:

On your remote Mac:

Create a folder named "Migration" in iCloud Drive and copy the following folders to "Migration":

Movies
Music
Pictures
Downloads

plus any other folders you want to migrate, except the Desktop and Documents folders.

Wait until the folders have been copied to iCloud Drive.
You can check the progress with the "pie chart" status icon next to "iCloud Drive" in the sidebar of a Finder window:

The synchronization is complete when the "pie chart" status icon is no longer shown.

If you use Terminal, you may want to compress your shell startup and history files (and any other hidden files of interest to you) and copy the resulting zip file to the “Migration” folder. For example, if you use bash and vi in a regular basis, you may use a command similar to this:
zip ~/Desktop/shell.zip .bashrc .bash_profile .bash_history .viminfo 




On your new Mac:

Copy the folders in the "Migration" iCloud Drive folder mentioned in the previous step to the appropriate locations.

Uncompress the zipped shell startup and history files (and any other files you added to the zip file) in the "Migration" folder in iCloud Drive  to your home folder.


After copying the folders and files, delete them from iCloud Drive to free up space.


The third step is to copy your settings.
WARNING: This is tricky and may not work correctly, but will hopefully at least transfer Finder and app settings and state. Other settings like printers and scanners can't be tranferred.

On your remote Mac:

Open your home folder in a Finder window, press ShiftCommand. to display all files, locate a folder named Library, open it and select:

Application Support
Caches
Saved Application State

and copy them to "Migration" (created above in iCloud Drive).
You will need to enter an administrator password to copy them.
These are usually large folders and the copy may take a while.

Press ShiftCommand. again to hide hidden files.



On your new Mac:

Open your home folder in a Finder window, press ShiftCommand. to display all files, locate a folder named Library and double-click it.

Make a backup of the following folders:

Application Support
Caches
Saved Application State
by copying them to the Desktop.

You will need to enter an administrator password to copy them.

Open the "Migration" folder in iCloud Drive.

Drag the following folders:

Application Support
Caches
Saved Application State

to the Library folder in your home folder.
When asked whether to replace files, answer yes. If a file can't be copied, skip the file.

Press ShiftCommand. again to hide hidden files.

Open an app (for example Safari) and verify that settings are correct and data (for example bookmarks) are correct.




The fourth step is to copy your passwords:

On your remote Mac, check whether "Passwords & Keychain" in System Settings > Apple Account > iCloud (in macOS Sonoma or earlier, open System Settings > Apple ID > iCloud instead) is turned on. If it isn't, enable "Sync this Mac":


In your new Mac, check whether "Passwords & Keychain" in System Settings > Apple Account > iCloud (in macOS Sonoma or earlier, open System Settings > Apple ID > iCloud instead) is turned on. If it isn't, enable "Sync this Mac".

Wait a couple of minutes (or proceed right away if the settings were already turned on on both Macs), open Safari, visit a site for which you have a username and password and verify that Safari suggests a password.
If the password is not available, see this Apple support article: If iCloud Keychain won't turn on or sync.


You can now delete the “Migration”, “Desktop” and “Documents” folders in iCloud Drive, and cancel your iCloud+ subscription.
Caveats
To the best of my knowledge, the procedure described above should transfer documents, movies, music and pictures without much trouble, bur app settings, as mentioned above, may not be transferred correctly, and may even corrupt your app settings on your new Mac.
System-wide settings can”t be transferred with this procedure.
